# How do I call a Class->Method from strings?

Tags: php, string, class, function, methods

It it possible to call a class and method from strings?

Something like:

```
// $_REQUEST['var'] = 'House-Kitchen';

$var = explode('-',$_REQUEST['var']);

echo $var[0]->$var[1];
```

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and ask why you want something like this?

Comment: Have you tried it? Your code should work... although your should *never* let user input directly affect the code that is executed in this way...

Comment: Well, or maybe $var[0]->$var[1]() for a method...But if $_REQUEST['var'] is 'this-authorize'? :)

Comment: Thats something like: $Class1->Edit($_REQUEST). So all values from a serialized form will go straight to the specific Class and Method. I dont need cases and switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is to try.

I did try :

```
$House = new stdClass();
$House->Kitchen = "visible result";

$_REQUEST['var'] = 'House-Kitchen';

$var = explode('-',$_REQUEST['var']);

echo $$var[0]->$var[1];
```

It works. Be careful : you need to use double $ for the first element (to use variable with `$var[0]` name).

And be very careful : it's a high security breach (you allow everyone to call methods on current defined class).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. its possible. If `$var[0]` is the **name of class** then following will work.

```
call_user_func(array($var[0], $var[1]));
```

If `$var[0]` is the **name of class instance** then following will work.

```
call_user_func(array(get_class(${$var[0]}), $var[1]));
```

Links:

1. [call_user_func](http://php.net/call_user_func)
2. [get_class](http://php.net/get_class)